# show custom text for products with specific woo commerce category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to show custom text for products in a specific woo commerce category.
This is the code I added to function.php , but it shows the text in the category page not the products page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'add_my_text' );
function add_my_text() {
    if ( is_product_category( 'category1' ) ) {
        echo '<p>This is my extra text.</p>';
    }    
}
```

p.s. is it any good to add "if (function_exists(add_action))" at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

To show the text in the Product page of this particular category, you should add the conditional Tag `is_product()` and check it has the right category with the `has_term()` function like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'add_my_text' );
function add_my_text() {
    //1st grab the product/post object for the current page if you don't already have it:
    global $post;
    //2nd you can get the product category term objects (the categories) for the product
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;
    //Then we just have to check whether a category is in the list:
    if ( is_product_category( 'category1' ) || is_product() && in_array( 'category1', $categories ) ) {
        echo '<p>This is my extra text.</p>';
    }    
}
```

And for the `if (function_exists(...` question, it's for a matter of backward compatibility as mentionned in this answer : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111318/136456

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems logical but the result didn't change.

Comment: What theme are you using? It's possible your theme doesn't use WooCommerce hooks. You could verify in your theme > woocommerce > single-product.php if **do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );** is here.

Comment: I'm using wood mart theme and yes it has the hook. maybe I should add the code in another location? I'm adding it in function.php

Comment: sorry, my fault, its not so easy to check the category because WC products can be in none, one or several categories. I updated my answer after testing it this time. And yes you can use that code in your **child theme**'s functions.php file

Comment: sorry still the same, actually now it doesn't show the text even in category page!

I get my themes function.php through this path :

wordpress dashboard> Appearance > Editor > function.php

Comment: is **category1** the slug of your category. What happens if you remove the category slug in the 1st if statement? It should display on every category.

Comment: Keep in mind, that if the slug of your category is in non-latin characters, for example cyrillic, arabic or etc, you will need to either turn the slug's characters into latin, or use iconv() or transliteration, if you do not want to change your slug.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_text' );

function add_text() {

if ( has_term( 'nail', 'product_cat' ) ) {
echo 'Something';
} elseif ( has_term( 'tables', 'product_cat' ) ) {
echo 'Something else';
}

}
```